# How do I remove the full-filespec from my VBA function?

Tags: excel, vba

I put my VBA function into an otherwise empty spreadsheet, put it on a common drive, and then pointed to it in the File|Options|Add-ins section. That all worked, until I had another user test it...
it turns out each usage of the function now has a file-spec in front of it (including my name in the path). How do I properly make my function ready for big-time?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Hello, I haven't seen a reply so I'm thinking I've posted in the wrong place. Where should I post my VBA question?

Comment: I'm wondering if I could find out what I need to do to get the fully qualified file-spec out of the reference to my new VBA function call?

Comment: Sorry, but I've been looking for some guidance from stack overflow, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly, or if it is still active.